# Unable to forward nginx in a docker container to localhost 3000

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm currently trying to configured nginx within a docker container to redirect to `localhost:3000` when I navigate to `localhost:8080`. From [reading the documentation it seems I need to map the ports](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#port-mapping) to redirect requests to port 80 in the container. However, when I build an image based on the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk --no-cache add nginx

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN mkdir -p /run/nginx

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and run the container mapping the port 8080 to port 80 with the following command:

```
docker run -p 8080:80  nginx-server
```

When I navigate to `localhost:8080` I'm not being redirected to localhost:3000 and I get

```
localhost didn’t send any data.
```

After doing some digging it seems I need to change my nginx configuration to point to [proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72284451).However, this did not work and when I make a request to localhost:8080 I get nothing. here is my nginx configuration:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       127.0.0.1;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try to add the port for the listener? E.g.:  `listen       127.0.0.1:80;`

Comment: this is probably not what you want. Since you are likely to use nginx for external traffic. External traffic wont understand host.docker.internal. You probably want to use the actual address of your server for the redirect.